# processing of hospital admission data using R

Tags: r

I have a set of hospital admission data that I need to process, I am stuck when trying to loop the data and pick up the stuff I need, here is the example:

```
Date Ward
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    A B
5    A
6    A
7    A  C
8       C
9       C
10      C
```

And I need them to be transformed into:

```
Ward Adm_Date Dis_Date
A    1        4
B    4        4
A    4        7
C    7        10
```

To put it in sentence, this is a admission record patient X who:

- go to ward A from day 1 to day 4
- go to ward B (maybe it's an ICU ward) for less than a day in day 4, and move back to ward A on that day
- stay in ward A from day 4 to day 7
- move to ward C from ward A from day 7 and stay in ward C till day 10

I am thinking of using `ddply` by filtering the ward but it is not OK since B will be "omitted" and the period of time for A is not broken down into 2 pieces.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What's the 'Ward' variable here? A character string? How complex can it get - more than two wards in a day? If you had three ward codes - say, "A D F" where you have "A B" how would you know if the patient went to D or F first? Would it matter? It's doable but might just need a loop keeping track of where the patient is on each iteration. Also, it's not lupus.

Comment: ward is a character string, and I don't think there can be more than 2 wards in a day, and yes, it is not lupus. ;)
currently I am using ddply and loop for that, but it is kinda slow (I have admission records of 8000 patients from 1/1/2009 to 31/9/2010)

Comment: While sketching an answer there's an ambiguity in your data that I found when my solution didnt quite match yours! You say that if the code is "A B" and then "A" then they are in B for less than a day. But what if they are in B for exactly one day? Would it then go "A" "B" "A"? The problem I am having in my code is that you don't know if the patient is going back to "A" when you see "A B" until you check the next record. And that affects the code, because your admission data for A in row 3 of your output is 4, and not 5 which is what I'd expect.... Maybe it is lupus.

Comment: You could post your current solution so we're be able to compare our solutions with your on edge cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat <- data.frame(Date=1:10,Ward=c(rep("A",3),"A B",rep("A",2),"A C",rep("C",3)))
dat$Ward <- as.character(dat$Ward)

# Change data to a "long" format

Date2 <- rep(dat$Date,nchar(gsub(" ","",dat$Ward)))
Ward2 <- unlist(strsplit(dat$Ward," "))
dat2 <- data.frame(Date=Date2,Ward=Ward2)
dat2$Ward <- as.character(dat2$Ward) # pesky factors!

# Create output

Ward3 <- unlist(strsplit(gsub("(\\w)\\1+","\\1",paste(dat2$Ward,collapse="")),""))

#helper function to find lengths of repeated characters, probably a better way of doing this

repCharLength <- function(str)
{
    out <- numeric(0)
    tmp <- 1
    for (i in 2:length(str))
        {
        if (str[i]!=str[i-1])
            {out<-c(out,tmp)
            tmp<-1}
        else
        tmp <- tmp+1
        }
    return(c(out,tmp))
}

stays <- repCharLength(dat2$Ward)

Adm_Date <- c(1,dat2$Date[cumsum(stays)[1:(length(stays)-1)]])
Dis_Date <- dat2$Date[cumsum(stays)]
dat3 <- data.frame(Ward=Ward3,Adm_Date=Adm_Date,Dis_Date=Dis_Date)

> dat3
  Ward Adm_Date Dis_Date
1    A        1        4
2    B        4        4
3    A        4        7
4    C        7       10
```

A bit more involved than I first thought, and there is probably a better way to get the stay lengths than using the helper function I wrote, but this seems to do the job.

**Edit**

In light of Spacedman's comment, there is a library function to calculate `Ward3` and `stays`:

```
Ward3 <- rle(dat2$Ward)$values
stays <- rle(dat2$Ward)$lengths
```

Comment: You want rle(foo)$lengths for repCharLength(foo). My semi-solution I referred to earlier was pretty similar, I didn't bother posting it since it was a) a bit wrong, and b) I knew someone would post a proper solution by the time I'd got back to a computer... :)

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks, I thought there would be a better way of doing it. I see it also outputs the ward order too so no need to bother with the complicated regex version :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a complex answer but you can transform your data

```
X <- data.frame(
    Date=1:10,
    Ward=c("A","A","A","A B","A","A","A   C","C","C","C"),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)

w <- strsplit(X$Ward," +")
n <- sapply(w, length)
X_mod <- data.frame(
    Date = rep(X$Date, n),
    Ward = unlist(w, FALSE, FALSE)
)
```

With `X_mod` you could write vectorized (=fast) solution. For start `with(X_mod, c(0,cumsum(Ward[-1]!=Ward[-length(Ward)])))` gives you id of visit.