# processing of hospital admission data using R (part II)

Tags: r, plyr

Thanks all for providing suggestion on the question [processing of hospital admission data using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131584/processing-of-hospital-admission-data-using-r), I have addition question on this issue, actually, it should be the task before that question.

Now I have a dataset like this:

```
Patient_ID Date Ward
P001       1    A
P001       2    A
P001       3    A
P001       4    A
P001       4    B
P001       5    B
P001       6    B
P001       7    B
P001       7    C
P001       8    B
P001       9    B
P001       10   B
```

I need to convert it into:

```
Patient_ID Date Ward
P001       1    A
P001       2    A
P001       3    A
P001       4    A;B
P001       5    B
P001       6    B
P001       7    B;C
P001       8    B
P001       9    B
P001       10   B
```

Currently I have convert it using `ddply`, code is attached below:

```
data <- ddply(data,
              c("Patient_ID", "Date"),
              function(df)
                {data.frame(Ward=paste(unique(df[,"Ward"]),collapse=";"))
                },
              .progress="text"
              )
```

This can solve my problem, but it is VERY slow (more than 20 minutes on a P4 3.2 machine) when the dataset is having 8818 `unique(Patients_ID)` and 1861 `unique(Date)`. How can I improve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something that works is this, assuming your data are in object `pdat`

```
res <- with(pdat,
            aggregate(Ward, by = list(Date = Date, Patient_ID = Patient_ID),
                      FUN = paste, collapse = ";"))
names(res)[3] <- "Ward"
res <- res[, c(2,1,3)]
```

and gives:

```
> res
   Patient_ID Date Ward
1        P001    1    A
2        P001    2    A
3        P001    3    A
4        P001    4  A;B
5        P001    5    B
6        P001    6    B
7        P001    7  B;C
8        P001    8    B
9        P001    9    B
10       P001   10    B
```

It should extend happily to more patients etc, and is quite a bit faster than your `ddply()` version:

```
> system.time(replicate(1000,{
+ res <- with(pdat,
+             aggregate(Ward, by = list(Date = Date, Patient_ID = Patient_ID),
+                       FUN = paste, collapse = ";"))
+ names(res)[3] <- "Ward"
+ res <- res[, c(2,1,3)]
+ }))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.113   0.002   2.137
```

vs

```
> system.time(replicate(1000,{
+ ddply(pdat,
+       c("Patient_ID", "Date"),
+       function(df)
+       data.frame(Ward=paste(unique(df[,"Ward"]),collapse=";"))
+       )
+ }))
   user  system elapsed 
 12.862   0.006  12.966
```

However, this doesn't mean that the `ddply()` cannot be speeded up - I'm not familiar with this package.

Whether the two versions scale in a similar manner - i.e. just because the `aggregate()` version is quicker in these repeated tests on simple data, doesn't mean you'll get the same benefit when applied to the much larger task - remains to be seen, but I'll leave you to test the two versions on small subsets of your data with more than a few patients to see how well they scale.

---

**Edit:**
A quick test - repeating the patient data you gave us to generate four new patients (giving 5 in total), all with same data, suggests that the aggregate one scales a bit better. Execution time for the `aggregate()` version went up to 4.6 second for the 1000 reps (~ a doubling) whereas the timing for the `ddply()` version went up to 52 seconds (~ a quadrupling).